# Is there a way to perform echo | tee during find -exec?

Tags: bash

I have a problem with a code similar to the following:

```
function echotee() { echo $1 | tee -a ${FILE}; }
export -f echotee

find . -delete -exec sh -c 'echotee "Deleting: {}"' \;
```

The function `echotee` usually works as expected. However, during the `-exec` it does not. Indeed, it just prints on the terminal, omitting `tee`.

Hoping the question is not too trivial, thanks in advance.

Comment: `sh` doesn't support inheriting functions, it's a `bash` extension. So use `bash -c`.

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: I tried, but the problem is not that. The execution does not fail. Apparently, it just do not consider the `tee`, after the `echo` on the terminal.

Comment: `find . -delete -printf "Deleting: %p\n" | tee "$FILE"`?

Comment: `find . -delete -printf "Deleting: %p\n" | tee "$FILE"` would probably work, but I would like to mantain `echotee` "central", as the standard way to print information.

Comment: @DavideFranchi: regarding your previous comment: it looks like a bad design choice! is there any serious reason you're considering it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `name()` instead of `function name()`.
2. You did not set nor export `FILE` variable.
3. sh does not support exporting functions. It's a  feature of `bash`, you have to call `bash`.
4. `sh -c ' .... "{}"'` will break on filenames containing `"` character. Put it as positional argument and use `$1`.
5. `$1` and `$FILE` expansions are not quoted and are subject to word splitting and filename expansion.
6. `echo $1` will break on filenames like `-e`. Prefer `printf`.
7. Check your scripts with shellcheck - it will catch many such mistakes.

I think you meant to:

```
FILE=/tmp/log.txt
echotee() { printf "%s\n" "$1" | tee -a "$FILE"; }
export -f echotee
export FILE
find . -exec bash -c 'echotee "Deleting: $1"' -- {} \;
```

But the version from Shawn with `-printf "Deleting: %p\n" | tee "$FILE"` looks just nicer.

I think spawning `tee` and pipe will be slower then, I think doing like so could be a bit faster:

```
echotee() { printf "%s\n" "$1" >> "$FILE"; printf "%s\n" "$1"; }
```

or like:

```
exec 10>>"$FILE"
echotee() { printf "%s\n" "$1" >&10; printf "%s\n" "$1"; }
```

You could remove the pipe either way, just:

```
echotee() { tee -a "$FILE" <<<"$1"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use this:

```
find . -delete -exec sh -c 'echo "Deleting: $1" | tee -a "$2"' _ {} "${FILE}" \;
```

No need to define and call a function.

---

You mentioned in a comment that you want to use `echotee` as a central point to print and log information. Have you considered a setup like this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Send all script output to console and logfile
LOGFILE="..."
exec > >(tee -ia "${LOGFILE}") 2>&1

find . -delete -printf "Deleting: %f\n"
```

or this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set up fd 3 to send output to console and logfile on demand
LOGFILE="..."
exec 3> >(tee -ia "${LOGFILE}")

find . -delete -printf "Deleting: %f\n" 1>&3 2>&1
```

Comment: Don't put the '{}' inside the arg to sh (it's not compliant, and will lead to strange surprises if there are funny symbols in the file name). Same for the expansion of FILE (should be quoted in some way).

Comment: That's no fixing anything. This would be better: `... -exec sh -c 'echo "Deleting: $1" | tee -a "$FILE"' _ {} \;`

Comment: Yes, I have considered such setup, but I need a script working with shell `sh`, not `bash`. Anyway, thank you for the detailed answer. The problem turned out to be `FILE` not exported.